# How to add more hyperledger channels in the blockchain marbles sample application

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

Trying out this blockchain application (https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/marbles). Got the basics working just fine and now want to explore further.

The current configuration for this works with a single channel. Can we add more channels just with configuration or does it need code changes as well? If yes, will appreciate guidelines/suggestions for that.

Answer (score 3):

To setup a channel you need to create a genesis block with configuration transaction, basically you need to use `configtxgen tool` to generate it. More documentation about how to use it could be found [here](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configtxgen.html).

There is also a [tutorial](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html) on setting your first network which covers pretty well stages you need to follow to create a new channel.